# Rails - multiple associations to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I'm building a Rails app to track expenses/debts among members of a group, let's say a household. So far I have models for Groups, Users and Expenses - the basics. Right now I'm trying to figure out the associations between Groups and Users. For example, a Group can have many users and a user can have/belong to many groups, so I set a HABTM association using a join table. But I'm confused because a Group can also have one owner, which is also a User. This is where I am right now:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_one :owner, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

There's currently an owner_id field on the Group table, but I'm getting a PostgreSQL Error `column users.group_id does not exist` when I try and do anything involving `group.owner`. I'm fairly lost - any ideas on the best way to represent multiple associations to the same model here?

Comment: `HABTM` already means that the group has many users, right? So one of those users must be the "owner" too. What you can do is using a `has_many :through` and use a field in that to specify the owner of a group.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I think I follow what you are trying to get at, this is a quick ERD created in Dia:

[image: simple erd]

It looks like you just need to add the direct association for ownership between a User and a Group. I used the column `owner_id` so the table and model are more clear and avoid confusion about multiple user_id columns. Then the following models will work:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    has_many :owned, :class_name => "Group", :foreign_key => "owner_id"
end
```

Comment: I did not notice double attribute `groups` for `User` in my code, plus for you.

Comment: Success! Looks like I had the `has_one-/belongs_to-` owner association switched in my Group model, and the :owned solution is perfect. Love the diagram too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :through => :membership
    has_one :owner, :class_name => "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :through => :membership
    has_many :owned, :class_name => "Group"
end
```

And create model `Membership` with `user_id` and `group_id`?